# Grafana alert missing loki sum query results

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki

We use the following `loki` query to sum errors per job:

[image: Grafana alert query]

[image: Alert evaluation time]

I know this works, cause when changing range to 1 hours it shows data:

[image: Alert query with data]

When using Grafana Explore, I can find a specific sum occurring at 03.02.2024 20:30:

[image: Grafana Explore sum]

But for this entry, there was no alert triggered, Grafana does not show a "**Pending**" state in the state history, nor an "**Alert**" state.

As the query builds a sum that can only go up over the selected range, once there is an error the last six minutes for every 5 minutes of evaluation, there shouldn't be any errors missing with this alert rule.

**Any idea why the alert would be missing errors?**